# Video Player/Library for Ubuntu with ratings and thumbs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, media-player, libraries

I've just made the switch to Ubuntu on my main PC and I've been looking for a media player that can:

- Play all the usual video formats
- Rate (and ideally, tag) each file
- Display thumbnails for each file

Other than that there isn't much I'm after.

Banshee comes close, but doesn't display thumbnails.

I've Google'd lots but I'm running out of search terms to try.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Cheers!

Comment: Good Banshee review: http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/reviews/2988.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about ratings, but [miro](http://www.getmiro.com/) sure offers lots of video formats and thumbnails.

Comment: I tried miro and for some reason (I can't remember why unfortunately - I've tried so many) it wasn't what I was after. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried boxee(http://www.boxee.tv/)? It is more of a Windows Media Center alternative. Its is free and does everything you mentioned. And does much more. It is one of the most elegant softwares of its kind. It recognizes movies, albums, tv shows. And pulls information, rating, vital info, box art, subtitle etc. It does lot more. Please check the feature list.

My recommendation is, install it, try it.

Comment: I've got it installed on our media pc and think it's great. However ideally I need this app to be windowed so I can do work whilst using it. I might take a look at Boxee though and see whether it runs in a window. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I has a windows version too. And you can hit '\' button in the keyboard while in fullscreen to get to window mode.

Answer (score 1):

[Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) has those features of maintaining library with tag information.

Answer (score 0):

Try VLC (VideoLAN Client) player. It is the jack of all cats!
In Ubuntu go to System menu | Administration | Synaptic Package Manager, type vlc in search box, install it and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably still going to have install codecs for the video formats, but I highly reccomend [Moovida](http://www.moovida.com/). It has a pretty different user interface, and is more suited to a full-screen interface but it does a lot of things really well.